# Why is async file writing slower than sync file writing?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles

I am currently trying to understand how `asyncio` works in Python. I want to speed up file writing using asynchronous file writing in the `aiofiles` library.

I have a synchronous writing function:

```py
def sync_writer():
    with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in range(500000):
            f.write(f"line#{i}\n")
```

and its asynchronous alternative that runs multiple asynchronous writers:

```py
import asyncio
import aiofiles

async def write_fun(file, writer_n, n_writers):
    for i in range(writer_n, 500000, n_writers):
        await file.write(f"line#{i}\n")

async def async_writer(n_writers):
    async with aiofiles.open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        await asyncio.gather(*[write_fun(f, i, n_writers) for i in range(n_writers)])
```

Then I run both of this functions and track their completion time. I run the asynchronous writing function with 10 writers:

```py
import time
async def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    await async_writer(10)
    print(time.time()-t1)

    t1 = time.time()
    sync_writer()
    print(time.time()-t1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

And the final time result is surprising for me because it took 36 seconds for the async function and only 0.33 seconds for sync function to write the file.

I think this is an IO-bound task, so asynchronous write should help here, but is doesn't.

Why is async writing so slow here? How to use `asyncio` and all the related libraries in order to actually get an advantage from it?

Comment: There's buffering in `file.write()`, both in Python and in the OS. It's already about as fast as it can go.

Comment: You can squeeze performance out of IO bound processes by doing something else during the IO (e.g. utilizing the CPU or IO to other devices). Writing to the same filesystem at the same time isn't something else, it's just adding unnecessary overhead to an already bottlenecked operation.

Comment: You didn't specify the operating system. At least Linux has very limited support for asynchronous local IO. From a brief glimpse at the aiofiles code, it seems like they use a thread pool to mimic true async IO. This is fine, but you are just adding more and more overhead. If you did this to do something else in parallel, that's fine. But you're not beating the blocking version on raw throughput or spent CPU cycles

Comment: Looking at the code a bit more it seems like they don't do anything fancy around buffered IO. They just dispatch every call to a threadpool executor. So you should only use it with write commands of reasonable size, e.g. 4 kiB, 64 kiB, or 1 MiB at a time. Not some tiny, single line. I could be missing something but it would explain the low performance if every line is one round-trip through the event loop to and from another thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `aiofiles` seems to operate is that each call is dispatched to a [threadpool executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=threadpool#threadpoolexecutor) which then simply calls the regular blocking file operation. So, every time you execute `await f.write(…)`, the following happens:

1. The operation is enqueued into the queue of the thread pool
2. The thread pool wakes up one of its threads
3. The thread calls the blocking function
4. The result is communicated back to the event loop

This wouldn't be so bad if it wasn't for these factors:

1. You try to write with multiple writers to the same file but writing to a single file with the standard Python API is inherently single-threaded. Multiple threads can't possibly provide a benefit. You'd need something like [`os.pwrite`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=pwrite#os.pwrite) for that
2. Each write operation is tiny with only a couple of bytes per line, making all overhead significant
3. File IO is buffered (typically 4 kiB), so most of the time, the threads do nothing but copy the tiny line into the file buffer. They don't even do anything that could block!
4. You don't have any other activity that the event loop could do while waiting for this operation

Contrary to popular believe parallel IO often makes sense, especially with modern SSDs and RAM bandwidth (meaning that parallel access to the page-cache is necessary to exhaust memory bandwidth). But python's API makes this hard to pull off with a single file. Overall, you get much better IO performance with multiple files and IO operations of reasonable size, for example 64 kiB at a time.

Here is a simple proof-of-concept attempt to fix your issues. What we do is buffer multiple write operations in the main thread until a buffer size limit is exceeded and only then do we schedule a write operation

```py
import io


class BufferedWriter:
    def __init__(self, asyncfile, bufsize=64*1024):
        self.asyncfile = asyncfile
        self.bufsize = bufsize
        self.buf = io.StringIO()

    async def write(self, text):
        if op := self.write_async(text):
            await op

    def write_async(self, text):
        buf = self.buf
        buf.write(text)
        return None if buf.tell() < self.bufsize else self.flush()

    def flush(self):
        buf = self.buf
        rtrn = self.asyncfile.write(buf.getvalue())
        buf.seek(0)
        buf.truncate()
        return rtrn


async def async_writer2():
    async with aiofiles.open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        buffered = BufferedWriter(f)
        for i in range(500000):
            await buffered.write(f"line#{i}\n")
        await buffered.flush()
```

On my system this takes 0.18 seconds compared to 11 seconds in your version or 0.07 seconds in the serial version. Not great performance but maybe a reasonable tradeoff to have the IO nonblocking

We can get better with some double-buffering. While a background thread writes to the output file, the main thread can fill the next buffer.

```py
async def async_writer3():
    def write_all(outfile):
        buffered = BufferedWriter(outfile)
        for i in range(500000):
            if async_op := buffered.write_async(f"line#{i}\n"):
                yield async_op
        yield buffered.flush()
    async with aiofiles.open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        last_write = None
        for writeop in write_all(f):
            if last_write:
                await last_write
            last_write = asyncio.create_task(writeop)
        if last_write:
            await last_write
```

This gets the runtime down to 0.14 seconds.

Note how we only keep one write operation running as a background task at any time. If we don't, there is a race condition between them and the order of output lines can get mixed. `aiofiles` does not ensure that parallel operations on the same file run in order of their scheduling.